# Insufficient memory to load Protected Mode

Tags: dos

I am trying to run an old DOS application that we use extensively at our company, but am getting the error 'Insufficient memory to load Protected Mode'.

This program runs fine everywhere except on the last three machines we've bought (2x Acer Veritons and an HP Pro).

Haven't been able to find anything in my Google searches so far.
I've tried in on Win7 Pro and Win8/8.1.  I tried it on the 2 Acers, then moved to an HP to see if it was a manufacturer specific hardware issue, but am encountering the same issue on the HP.

Comment: Ironically, this may be an overflow on memory (e.g. > 2GB of RAM may be detected as 'negative'). Have you tried running it under [DOSBox and tweak the configured EMS / XMS settings](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, one of the issues is that the application is just a shortcut to a shared runtime on the server so I'm not sure that it will work with DOSBox.  Also, this application is running fine on several boxes with 4GB already, it is just the last three that seem to have this issue.

Comment: Do you use the compatibility modes?  Adjusting memory etc?

Comment: It won't adjust compatibility since it's a link to an application on a network drive.